# How to display stored images in Spring Boot using Angular 4?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and Angular 4.
I have uploaded an image to the project location.
When I try to view the uploaded image, it is not displayed but an error is thrown. 
How can I view the image?

**ang.html:**

```
<button type="button" class="button btn-info" 
                            (click)='showInfo()'>ShowImages</button>
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">List of Images</div>
                    <img [src]="fileUploads">
                </div>
```

**components.ts:**

```
fileUploads: any;
  sid: number = 1;
  showInfo() {   
    this.drugservice.getFiles(this.sid).subscribe(data => {this.fileUploads = data, alert(data)}), err => {
      console.log('Error Occured showInfo');
    };
  }
```

**service.ts**

```
getFiles(id: number): any {
  return this.http.get(this.getFileuploadedURL+'/'+id, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map(
  (res) => {
      return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'image/png' })
  });
}
```

**springBoot Controller:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getUploadfiles/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getImage(@PathVariable Integer id) throws IOException {
        String filename = "01";
        System.out.println("id : " + id);
        File serverFile = new File(rootLocation + "\\" + filename + ".jpg");
        System.out.println("serverFile : " + serverFile);        
        return Files.readAllBytes(serverFile.toPath());
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your mapping in **spring boot controller** to:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getUploadfiles/{id}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
```

this will indicate that the returned object must be handled as a JPEG image.

In Angular create the required path to image and pass is to the img element, eg:

**components.ts:**

```
fileUrl = '/getUploadfiles/1';
```

**ang.html:**

```
<img [src]="fileUrl">
```